RTK query mutation catch block
I am using RTK query for comunication with API. When mutation fails, I need dispatch some alert, like follows:
const [addPost, {
    isError,
    error,
}] = useAddPostMutation()
...
useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
        dispatch(setAlert(error))
    }
}, [isError])

It works ok.
But now, I would like to omit useEffect and I found in official docs (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) this code.
addPost({ id: 1, name: 'Example' })
  .unwrap()
  .then((payload) => console.log('fulfilled', payload))
  .catch((error) => console.error('rejected', error))

then block works ok, but there is some problem with catch block. I got this error message:
rejected TypeError: description(...) is undefined

I tried it without unwrap(), it falls every time into then block and get same error.
addPost({ id: 1, name: 'Example' })
  .then((payload) => console.log('fulfilled', payload))
  .catch((error) => console.error('rejected', error))

fulfilled 
Object { error: TypeError }


Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so we can see what going on around it. Can you share the addPost action creator and any other code you think might be relevant?

I tried some another mutation addRecipe from my codebase and it works. So I look at differencies and I found it in action creators.
addRecipe: build.mutation({
    query: (payload) => {
        const { form } = payload
        return {
            url: '...',
            method: 'POST',
            body: form
        }
    },
    invalidatesTags: []
}),

-->
rejected 
{
  "status": 400,
  "data": {
    "message": "..."
  }
}

addPost: build.mutation({
    query: (payload) => {
        const { form } = payload
        return {
            url: '...',
            method: 'POST',
            body: form
        }
    },
    invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result) return ['...']
    }
}),

-->
rejected TypeError: description(...) is undefined

So the problem is in invalidatesTags section. Actually I don't remember why I don't use the first one method -  invalidatesTags: [] everywhere.
Solution is probably quite easy.
invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
    if (result) return ['...']
    return [] // I have to return empty array of tags
}

